# Trouble passing data

Tags: ios, swift

I’m having trouble passing data via prepareForSegue from MainVC to EditVC. The gist of the problem is I’m trying to edit quote info(quote and author) already entered(saved in a Firestore database). When swiping(UIContextualAction) and tap on edit, it’s suppose to pass the data on to the EditVC where it’ll put the quote text and author text in their own UITextView where it’s editable. Once you edit the text, hit save and it’ll update the entry in Firestore; then MainVC reloads to update it’s view. The segue to the EditVC works flawlessly but it doesn’t display the quote & author text in their respective text views. I’ve been banging my head against the wall for 3 days trying to figure it out. Any help or guidance from you all is greatly appreciated. I can provide the Github link upon request.

**MainVC:**

```
    }
        let edit = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (action, view, nil) in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toEditQuote", sender: self.quotes)
            print("Segue initiated")
        }
        edit.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1764705926, green: 0.4980392158, blue: 0.7568627596, alpha: 1)
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, edit])
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        print("preparing to segue")
        if let destination = segue.destination as? EditQuoteVC {
            print("Destination = EditQuoteVC")
            if let quoteData = sender as? Quote {
                print("data passing")
                destination.quoteTxt = quoteData.quoteTxt
                destination.authorTxt = quoteData.authorTxt
                print("data passed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EditQuoteVC(destination)**

```
class EditQuoteVC: UIViewController {

//Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var quoteText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var authorText: UITextView!

//Variables
var quoteTxt: String!
var authorTxt: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
quoteText.text = quoteTxt
authorText.text = authorTxt
}
```

**Quote.swift**

```
class Quote {

    private(set) var quoteTxt: String!
    private(set) var authorTxt: String!
    private(set) var timestamp: Date!
    private(set) var userId: String!
    private(set) var documentID: String!


    init(quote: String, author: String, timestamp: Date, userId: String, documentID: String) {

        self.quoteTxt = quote
        self.authorTxt = "- \(author)"
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.userId = userId
        self.documentID = documentID
    }
    class func parseData(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?) -> [Quote] {
        var quotes = [Quote]()
        guard let snap = snapshot else { return quotes}
        for document in snap.documents { //Grabs the documents...
            let data = document.data()
            let quote = data[QUOTE_TEXT] as? String ?? ""
            let author = data[AUTHOR_TEXT] as? String ?? ""
            let timestamp = data[TIMESTAMP] as? Date ?? Date()
            let userId = data[USER_ID] as? String ?? ""
            let documentID = document.documentID

            let newQuote = Quote(quote: quote, author: author, timestamp: timestamp, userId: userId, documentID: documentID)
            quotes.append(newQuote)
        }
        return quotes
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set any breakpoints in MainVC? Specifically, is your nested if code getting hit? And is `quoteData` properly populated as expected?

Comment: In your `prepareForSegue` you are expecting `sender` to be an instance of `QuoteData` but in your action you are setting `sender` to `nil` when you call `performSegue`.  Please show the `let edit...` code in context and provide details of how your quotes are stored for display in your tableview; presumably an array of `QuoteData`

Comment: Also, why do you have the `QuoteData` class? It looks like the `Quote` class already does what you need.

Comment: @dfd I haven't used breakpoints just print statements in `performSegue` and `prepareForSegue`. Console shows `performSegue` being initiated but not `prepareForSegue`.

@Paulw11 I see your point on using QuoteData class. I have commented it out and just used the `Quote` data model which I have added above(Quote.swift). Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Print statements *should* be okay in place of breakpoints, but you don't have them in your posted code... thus my "should". As @GntlmnBndt implies in his answer, several possibilities are happening, including that `prepareForSegue` is in fact being processed but the logic inside it is wrong. (The only other thing IMHO? `toEditQuote` is improperly spelled from what you named it in the storyboard.) Have you tried changing the line as suggested to `segue.destination`?

Comment: @dfd sorry, I had added the print statements after posting the code here. I have edited the post to reflect those print statements. I have implemented @GntimnBndt's suggestion but it still doesn't work(above code also reflects that). I double-checked the segue identifier in storyboard; copy and pasted the identifier to the `withIdentifier`to make sure there were no typos. Still no dice :/ I'll continue tinkering with the logic. I appreciate the help thus far.

Comment: Two more thoughts. Maybe add two more print statements - one as the first line in `prepareForSefue` and one in between the if statements. This should clarify that in fact it isn't being hit, and also clarify if there an issue with the conditions in the `if let` statements.Second, I don't know much about Firestore (or Firebase if that's what you mean, but if there a cloud database being pinged in the app I wonder the root cause is due to a latency problem.

Comment: @dfd looks like adding those two print statements helped narrow down the issue. I updated the MainVC up above. `"preparing to segue"`, `"Destination = EditQuoteVC"` and `"Segue initiated"` appear in the console in that order; `"data passing"` and `"data passed"` do not. As for Firestore, yeah it's the same as Firebase, however Xcode acts funny sometimes w/o Firestore imported; Firebase should be sufficient. I think the latency isn't the problem, it's quite fast when adding or deleting from the app or the database itself. You did encourage me to double-check the read/write rules but they're ok.

Comment: Sounds like you've narrow it to `if let quoteData = sender as? Quote` being `nil` for some reason. This is *now* the first time (with current code edits) you've referenced `sender`. It's also the first local reference to class `Quote`. On cursory glance? Does `sender` have everything needed to be able to cast it as `Quote`? Or do you need to change the left side of your second `if` condition to something like `if let quoteData = destination.parseData as? [Quote]`?

Comment: Scratch some of my last reply (don't wish to edit it again though). `parseData returns an array of quotes (`[Quote]`) and I didn't see that `sender` should only have a *single* `Quote`. Still, with this last code you posted, look at *both* `sender` and `destination`. Do either of these have, well, either a `Quote` or `[Quote]`? It appears you have either a casting issue (you should be using `destination` instead of `sender`) or a looping one (something contains an array where you are coding for a single instance) in your if statement.

Comment: @dfd
*Do either of these have, well, either a Quote or [Quote]?*: Yes, each row contains a quote, author and timestamp but all I want to grab is the quote and author text. When swiping left on each cell, it gives the option to edit or delete. Delete works fine; it deletes it from the database and the tableview reloads to the latest snapshot of the database. *It appears you have either a casting issue*: I do believe you're right. I tried `destination` instead of `sender` but it warns me saying _Cast from 'EditQuoteVC' to unrelated type 'Quote' always fails_ on that specific line.

Answer (score 1):

In your prepareForSegue function, you are assigning destination to sender. It should be:

```
if let destination = segue.destination as? EditQuoteVC
```